# x post awaiting review but review queue is empty: Is this a bug?

Tags: support, bug, reviews

This is what I see on my screen
[image]

Is this a bug or am I missing some underlying info?

Comment: From the duplicate I linked: "once you cross 10k rep -- the review counter in the statusbar changes to show the amount of reviews in-flight on the site as a whole"